# How to remove specific QUERY_STRING parameter in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, parameters, query-string

I need a proper solution to delete the URL parameter.

Example:

Input: https://www.hostever.com/blackfriday/?fbclid=IwAR3s1aVKUQELAb0EGW9_mh4qyR-i9ZqfNjFFB6xv_MoNRal2cH--lKofqHM

Output: https://www.hostever.com/blackfriday/

So it will delete the **fbclid=**

```
Input: https://www.hostever.com/?s=blogger
Output: https://www.hostever.com/?s=blogger
No need to change other parameters except **fbclid=**
```

I( need to delete only **fbclid=** this one from the URL.

Now I am using this, but the problem is with many parameters.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=""
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^p=.*
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=.*
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^s=.*
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin.*
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Please help me, How can I delete a specific parameter from the URL with .htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Stephen had the right idea.  But for what it's worth, I only needed one rule to remove three types of trackers:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)(fbclid|gclid|utm_)[^\&]*\&(.*)$ 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1%3 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

I needed this for a Wordpress blog, because when Wordpress tried to process parameters, the bogus ones caused a 404.  (Even when the URI was to a non-Wordpress static page on the site!)

The first set of parentheses matches everything before either of the three bad guys.  The third matches everything after the `&`.  The condition then puts the first and third together.  Stephen's comment about it depending on the `&` being present is correct—it does not remove the `fbclid`! (unless followed by an ampersand).  And yet, for reasons I don't understand, adding this rule made Wordpress stop saying 404 on links from Facebook.

However, my rule will not work if `fbclid` is in the URI outside of the parameters.  For example, any page on a domain named `fbclid-sucks.com`  :-)

Comment: That won't remove `?fbclid=abc` but it will remove `?fbclid=abc&` (it requires the trailing `&`).

Comment: It will also remove `?xfbclid=abc&` because it is based on a bug in my answer.

Comment: I see your point about the trailing &, yet it somehow worked!  It _will_ remove fbclid which or without the ? but I don't want to remove the ? because there could be legitimate parameters.  If there is an xfbclid, it will remove the whole name and value except for the 'x'  If I ever run into a URI stupidly using xfbclid as a parameter name, I'll fix that.  :-)  For now, this lets me put links to my blog on Facebook without giving people 404.  And if I choose to put a static page in the same top level directory as the blog, this also prevents the 404.

Answer (score 0):

I have adapted the answer from [Mod_rewrite delete parameter in 301 Redirect](https://serverfault.com/questions/218044/mod-rewrite-delete-parameter-in-301-redirect):

```
# Remove fbclid when it is the only URL parameter
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^fbclid=[^\&]*$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
# Remove fbclid when it is the last URL parameter
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)fbclid=[^\&]*$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1 [R=301,L]
# Remove fbclid when it is in the middle of the URL parameters
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)\&fbclid=[^\&]*\&(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [R=301,L]
```

- `[^\&]*` is any number of characters that are not `&`, ie. a parameter value.
- `$1` is the captured group from the parenthesis in the rewrite rule
- `%1` is the captured group from the first set of parenthesis in the rewrite condition.
- `%2` is the captured group from the second set of parenthesis in the rewrite condition

I don't see a way of implementing this as a single rule.

Comment: Why wouldn't the third rule take care of the other two?

Comment: The third rule was missing `\&` which I just added.  It won't deal with starting with or ending with the parameter because it isn't surrounded by `&` in those cases.